# I want to make a variable in my views.py which changes depending the name of the urlpattern used

Tags: python, django, django-views

Here's my code. whatever urlpattern is chosen: I want the name of it to be stored as `url` in views.py. Which is then used in queryset filter().

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^news/', BoxesView.as_view(), name='news'),
url(r'^sport/', BoxesView.as_view(), name='sport'),
url(r'^cars/', BoxesView.as_view(), name='cars'),
```

**views.py**

```
class BoxesView(ListView):
    url = #urlname to go here
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset_list = Post.objects.all().filter(category=url)
```

**models.py**

```
category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
```

**choices.py**

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('1', 'news'),
    ('2', 'sport'),
    ('3', 'cars'),

)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace your url.py by something like this:

```
url(r'(?P<keyword>\w+)/$', BoxesView.as_view())
```

This changes your address into an url parameter which you can then access the in your methods like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
            url = self.kwargs['keyword']
            queryset_list = Post.objects.all().filter(category=url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the name of the view

```
 url = resolve(self.request.path_info).url_name
```

UPDATE: Added "self." which is needed when using generic views. And don't forget to import:

```
 from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
```